# Purpose of [^\x20-\x7E] in regular expressions

Tags: regex

```
 [^\x20-\x7E]
```

I saw this pattern used for a regular expression in which the goal was to remove non-ascii 
characters from a string. What does it mean?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It says something like: *all characters that are not (`^`) in the range `\x20-\x7E` (hex `0x20` to `0x7E`).*

According to http://www.asciitable.com/, those are characters from space to `~`.

Comment: i.e. the printable characters

Comment: It's good to note that you can also use APIs to do the check. For instance, in Java you can use java.lang.Character.isISOControl(character) and similar methods that make your code more readable.

Comment: There are languages that does not have a API for such purposes. In PHP you have to do something like this to extract special characters:preg_replace_callback('/[^\x20-\x7f]/', function($match) {
    return DO_SOMETHING_WITH_SPECIAL_CHARS($match[0]);
}, $url);

Answer (score 9):

It means match any characters that are not printing characters.

Printing characters include a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9 and symbols such as ",;$#% etc.

```
^ not
\x20 hex code for space character
- to 
\x7e hex code for ~ (tilde) character
```

All the ascii printing characters fall between these two.

This statement matches non ascii characters as well as ascii control (non printing) characters such as bell, tab, null and others.

Look at

```
man ascii
```

on a unix system to see which characters it matches.

In perl, you could also write this as

```
[^ -~]
```

or

```
[[:^cntrl:]]
```

This last one is slightly different, in that it matches any non control character, including extended ascii (e.g. accented characters) and unicode.

You may not want to restrict yourself to just ascii, since non US locations often use valid printing characters outside this small range, e.g. øüéåç...

Comment: I think you meant [^[:print:]] for that last one. POSIX character class notation includes the square brackets as well as the colons, and the whole thing has to be placed inside another set of square brackets. (And of course, [:cntrl:] is the wrong class.) However, POSIX classes are also supposed to be locale-sensitive, which means they could match, eg, accented letters as well as the basic ASCII set.

Comment: Ah yes, that was sloppy (it was late).  cntrl is indeed different to the previous ones, in the sense that it will include printing characters in the extended ascii and even unicode ranges, but I believe that it's likely that's what was intended.

Comment: I would advise leaving the POSIX character classes alone, especially in a case like this, where we don't know which regex flavor is being used, which OS it's running on, or in which locale. All of those factors can change their behavior.

Comment: This answer is most completed: [^\x20-\x7E] is not restricted to 'not printing characters'. It matches also to NON-ASCII characters like 'ä', 'ö' et cetera. I think, one uses  [^\x20-\x7E] often to do something with such special characters (umlauts).

Answer (score 3):

It means "anything that isn't a character code in the hexadecimal range 0x20 to 0x7E, i.e. 32 to 126".

Answer (score 2):

The caret (^) inside the brackets [] means "not", and the \x20-\x7E denotes a range of ascii characters, where \x20 (space) is the beginning of the range, and \x7E (~) is the end. It is basically anything that is not a letter, number, or common punctuation.