# t-sql: replace function truncates when binary data type is used

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace

here is the code to re-produce the issue:

```
DECLARE @VBIN BINARY(50)
DECLARE @PASS NVARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @TEXT NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @TEXT = '123456123789'
SET @PASS = '123'
SET @VBIN = CONVERT(BINARY, N'321')
SELECT REPLACE(@TEXT, @PASS,  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @VBIN))
```

would return
'321' insetead of '321456321789'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `binary(50)` will pad with `0x00` to reach the fixed length of 50 and that is generally treated as a string terminator.

You see the same behaviour with

```
SELECT N'The quick brown ' +  NCHAR(0) + N' fox jumped over the lazy dog.'
```

The data is actually still there after the `REPLACE`. It is in the attempt to display it as a string that truncation occurs.

```
DECLARE @VBIN BINARY(50)
DECLARE @PASS NVARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @TEXT NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @TEXT = '123456123789'
SET @PASS = '123'
SET @VBIN = CONVERT(BINARY, N'321')

SELECT REPLACE(@TEXT, @PASS,  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @VBIN))
SELECT DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@TEXT, @PASS,  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @VBIN))) /*112*/

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@TEXT, @PASS,  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @VBIN)) AS VARBINARY(112))
```

Using `varbinary` rather than `binary` would avoid the issue but I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do here anyway.

Comment: thanks Martin, in your answer "SELECT N'The quick brown ' +  NCHAR(0) + N' fox jumped over the lazy dog.'" led me to the right direction, for the solution i used a function from another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259622/how-do-i-remove-extended-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-t-sql) to remove non ascii charachters form the string and now string does not terminates and i do get the desired output '321456321789'