# SSRS report discard selected value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have SSRS 2012. When I load report page url, select all parameters values and hit button "view report", all my parameters discarded to blank and nothing happens. Report is not rendered. And web page is looks like I just load it.

But if I load project with this report to the Visual Studio and run report from there all is fine.

I have been searched the web, but with no luck. Please help.

**Update**

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3368.0 (X64) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200)

Comment: Are you using the same credentials to execute the report in Visual Studio as you are in the Report Viewer URL?

Comment: @RonSmith Yes, the same. And I'm local admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all checks and researches I think we have this issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2863256

Answer (score 0):

My first thought: Are there any inter-dependencies between your parameters that might be causing a failure when an invalid combination is selected?

***Added***

There are several other things to check:

1. Whenever you have more than one parameter, the second parameter is treated as dependent on the first. Therefore, if there is any issue with the first parameter, the second parameter will fail (and empty/disable itself). Look to number 2 as tp why your first parameter could fail and cause a domino effect on the other parameter(s).
2. I found [this blog](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/101/posts/13323/ssrs-45-there-is-an-error-in-xml-document.aspx) discussing that non-printable characters can cause failures in SSRS 2005, and I found some other sites suggesting the issue may persist in later versions as well. If this is the problem, you'll have to remove the characters before you can continue. See [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259622/how-do-i-remove-extended-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-t-sql) as a starting point.
3. Double-check how you assign default values to the parameters. I haven't seen this happen with two parameters, but if you have three and the second is missing a default value and the third isn't, it can cause problems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, there are 2 independent lists of parameters.

Comment: We have cyrillic characters in paremeters, but they are printable. As I could see we have not non-printable characters. Also cyrillic characters is used only as label field, value field is integer IDs.

Comment: We have 21 parameters in this report. They are integers, dates, strings, multiple and single values, allow nulls and don't allow nulls, not all of them have default values. But we have problems only with 2 parameters. Could you explain how missing a default value can cause problems?

Comment: When loading a report, SSRS will try to load each parameter in order. The first parameter that either has no default value or that cannot be filled due to conflicting dependencies with a prior parameter will either not be filled or possibly disabled until the it has the information it needs to move forward. Therefore, if you're using queries to define available and default values for your parameters, and one of the earlier parameters is leading to invalid options for a later parameter, it will cause problems, leading some or all subsequent parameters to be empty or disabled.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the two that are causing the issue as well as where the fall within the 21? Are they visible, hidden, internal? Are their values entered by the user, hard-coded as a list, or populated from a query?

Comment: They are populated from a query, integer data type, allow multiple values, visible, no default value. SQL query returns table that has 2 columns: ID (tinyint) and Name (nvarchar, contains cyrillic characters). ID is used as value field and Name as label field. Second parameter is like first. SQL query is very simple and working fine.

Comment: Is it a single query for both parameters? I can't find it again, but I seem to recall that you cannot use the same query to populate two multivalue parameters. Each parameter must have its own query.

Comment: No, each parameter has its own query. Sorry, I incorrectly expressed my thoughts.

Comment: Sorry, Alex, but I'm all out of ideas. I'm upvoting your question so maybe it will be seen by a few more people that may know more.