# Remove ASCII Extended Characters 128 onwards (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a simple way to remove extended ASCII characters in a varchar(max).  I want to remove all ASCII characters from 128 onwards. eg - ù,ç,Ä

I have tried this solution and its not working, I think its because they are still valid ASCII characters?

[How do I remove extended ASCII characters from a string in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259622/how-do-i-remove-extended-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-t-sql)

Thanks

Comment: Is this gonna be a part of a trigger code? To avoid those values in the future?

Comment: Use the linked answer, change `IF UNICODE(@nchar) between 32 and 255` to `IF UNICODE(@nchar) < 128`

Comment: The values are already in a column so either a function or Update statement will do?

Comment: @AlexK., as the linked answer is using a loop, I think this might be done better (see my answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove extended ASCII characters from a string in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259622/how-do-i-remove-extended-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 3):

The linked solution is using a loop which is - if possible - something you should avoid.

My solution is completely inlineable, it's easy to create an UDF (or maybe even better: an inline TVF) from this.

The idea: Create a set of running numbers (here it's limited with the count of objects in sys.objects, but there are tons of example how to create a numbers tally on the fly). In the second CTE the strings are splitted to single characters. The final select comes back with the cleaned string.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, EvilString NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl(EvilString) VALUES('ËËËËeeeeËËËË'),('ËaËËbËeeeeËËËcË');

WITH RunningNumbers AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nmbr
    FROM sys.objects
)
,SingleChars AS
(
    SELECT tbl.ID,rn.Nmbr,SUBSTRING(tbl.EvilString,rn.Nmbr,1) AS Chr
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(LEN(tbl.EvilString)) Nmbr FROM RunningNumbers) AS rn 
)
SELECT ID,EvilString
      ,(
        SELECT '' + Chr 
        FROM SingleChars AS sc
        WHERE sc.ID=tbl.ID AND ASCII(Chr)<128
        ORDER BY sc.Nmbr
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ) AS GoodString
FROM @tbl As tbl
```

The result

```
1   ËËËËeeeeËËËË    eeee
2   ËaËËbËeeeeËËËcË abeeeec
```

[Here is another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32048968/5089204) from me where this approach is used to replace all *special* characters with *secure* characters to get *plain latin*

Comment: First +1 for the good solution and the alias "EvilString"... I know this is an old thread but... This will blow up if the string contains reserved XML characters or any spaces.  I would suggest changing `FOR XML PATH('')` to `FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE` and including `.value('(text())[1]','varchar(8000)')` right before your `AS GoodString` alias; e.g. change `...) AS GoodString` to `...).value('(text())[1]','varchar(8000)') AS GoodString`. Since this post 2017 added STRING_AGG which circumvents the XML character issue.