# How to trim empty spaces in SQL Insert Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below query which insert records to the Table does not trim the empty space.

```
Insert into MyTable (MyColumn)
select RTRIM(LTRIM(rowvalue)) from #temptable
```

Alternatively, if i assign to a variable and insert back, empty spaces are trimmed.

```
Declare @var varchar(max)
set @var = (    select RTRIM(LTRIM(rowvalue)) from #temptable  )
go
Insert into MyTable (MyColumn) values ( @var)
```

Instead of assigning, is there a way to trim the empty spaces in the Insert query.

Comment: Your original insert statement absolutely will remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Your second approach will fail if `subquery` return more than one row.

Comment: it is just a sample syntax

Comment: @SeanLange , Original insert query is not trimming the empty space

Comment: Does `CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(rowvalue)) AS VARCHAR(max))` work in your first? What is the column type of `rowvalue` in your temp table?

Comment: It absolutely will remove leading and trailing spaces. Maybe you have characters that are not spaces?

Comment: just note tsql has `TRIM` function which is analogue of `rtrim(ltrim(...))`

Comment: Please post sample data and results.

Comment: @JNevill , Column has the datatype : VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL

Comment: If it's not trimming the spaces it may be that you have high ASCII characters in the field.

Comment: @SeanLange , that could be possible .. of having character which is not visbile.. such as dot or something ..else

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have high ASCII characters in the field.  Try this and see if the result comes back, it checks whether the field has characters between 1-31 and 127-255.

```
-- See if it's in the low ASCII range
SELECT *      
FROM #temp      
WHERE rowvalue LIKE '%[' + CHAR(1)+ '-' +CHAR(31)+']%'  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2

-- See if it's in the high ASCII range
SELECT *      
FROM #temp      
WHERE rowvalue LIKE '%[' + CHAR(127)+ '-' +CHAR(255)+']%'  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
```

If the record comes back you may need to replace the character in order to remove it.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259622/how-do-i-remove-extended-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-t-sql)