# T SQL Remove ASCII character from SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, openquery, notin

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

I have the below SQL statement to find unmatched records.  However, it is now working correctly as the field 'dsc' in the OPENQUERY actually contains a horizontal tab (ASCII char 009) before the string values:

```
SELECT [E_Code]
FROM [Person] P
WHERE P.E_Code NOT IN (
        SELECT dsc
        FROM OPENQUERY(svr01, 'select "dsc" from TST.eth')
        )
```

How do I remove ASCII char 009 from the dsc field?  I have tried LTRIM to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use substring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove extended ASCII characters from a string in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259622/how-do-i-remove-extended-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-t-sql)

Comment: @xXx sorry no. I created the function and can see it but when I try to run it I just receive: 'RemoveNonASCII' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20) = CONCAT('This is a tab--> ', '<--');
SELECT @str, REPLACE(@str, CHAR(9), '');


SELECT [E_Code]
FROM [Person] P
WHERE P.E_Code NOT IN (
        SELECT REPLACE(dsc, CHAR(9), '')
        FROM OPENQUERY(svr01, 'select "dsc" from TST.eth')
    )
```

Comment: thanks but how does this help my original question?

Answer (score 0):

Alter max recursion and create the following

```
    Create Function dbo.ASCIICleaner(@inputstring nvarchar(max))
    Returns nvarchar(max)
    BEGIN
    Declare @returnValue nvarchar(max) = '';
    with lengths as 
    (
        select @inputstring data, len(@inputstring) length,1 start
    )

    ,recurv as 
    (
        select data,length,UNICODE(substring(data,start,1)) chari ,start from lengths where start= 1
        union all
        select  data,length,UNICODE(substring(data,start+1,1)),start+1 from recurv where length > start
    )

    select @returnValue+= char(chari) 
    from recurv 
    where chari between 32 and 127
    order by start asc

    return @returnValue

    END


    select dbo.ASCIICleaner('aËbËcËDËEËF')
```

abcDEF will be returned

Comment: little explanation of your code will be very helpful

Comment: I'll admit it could have been cleaner, By using a recursive cte you can identify characters that you want to exclude, in this case anything that is not extended character set, the only limitation is the maximum size of a recursive cte is 32767.

Comment: Meant to say, anything that is extended char set will be removed.